# Доработка алгоритма возведения в степень

Tags: алгоритм, c++

Добрый вечер, возникла следующая проблема при возведении в степень. На одной из итераций возникает такая ситуация что r =70579 a= 30733 и результате их перемножения получается 2 169 104 407. Следовательно мы выходим за диапазон типа int. И следовательно дальнейшие вычисления не верные. Так вот подскажите идею как можно усовершенствовать алгоритм, не изменяя типы переменных с int на __int64?

```
int r = 1, a = 2, b = 40423, n = 71273;

for (int i = 1; i <= b; i++) {
r = r * a;
r = r % n;
}
Memo1->Lines->Add(IntToStr(r));
```

P.S. ещё раз повторюсь, менять тип переменных с int на long long или же на __int64 в моём случае не катит т.к. планирую переносить впоследствии на arduino. Помогите, уже 4 часа бьюсь голова уже пухнет.

P.S.S. была идейка делить r пополам, потом делить n пополам, брать от каждой части  r1 % n1 и r2 и n2 а потом результат складывать, но мне кажется что это не есть гуд.

Comment: @Никола Кривошея как-то Вы непонятно написали. В Вашем примере `a=2`, но никак не 30733. Покажите реальный пример. 

Если r или a больше n, то берите модуль до умножения. Если меньше, то возможны варианты. Не исключено, что придётся мудрить с умножением (в avr8 умножение int32 всё равно программное)

Comment: а будет равно  30733 на какой-то определённой итерации. Это и есть конкретный пример.

Comment: 1. А вы зачем в RSA лезете, если толком с ним не знакомы? Кто так в степень возводит? RSA и так медленный, а вы его еще сильнее затупляете. Гуглите быстрое возведение в степень.

2. При делении на 2 кол-во бит уменьшается на 1, а переполнение уже возможно при умножении (n^0.5 + 1) бит. Оно возможно даже при замене умножения сложением (грубо - n = 2^(n+1) - 1, r = n - 1, a = 2).

Так что мутить с умножением явно придется - перед каждой операцией проверять возможность переполнения.

Может стоит найти способ использовать что-то типа int64?

Comment: Я не говорю, что не надо этим заниматься, если раньше не занимались, просто везде, где я встречал RSA - везде этот момент рассматривался, т.к. он значительно сокращает количество умножений.

Что такое arduino не знаю, но поиск дал какую-то библиотеку, которая вроде как позволяет использовать Int64, так что может быть вместо танцев с бубном все-таки найти возможность использовать int64? Это значительно упростит вам жизнь )

Comment: @BOPOH - посмотрите на предыдущие вопросы от @Никола Кривошея - там я уже приводил пример того, как делать быстрое возведение в степень. Так что с этим проблем нет.

@Никола Кривошея Раз так - придется Вам вспомнить, как делают умножения столбиком. Только если в классическом умножении один разряд - это от - 0 до 9, то Вам оптимально брать от 0 до 255 (по байту). Таким образом вместо int используете массив с 4 байт. И перемножаете столбиком (нужно будет 16 умножений и 9-10 сложений). Аналогично и деление. Да, для результатов умножения нужен будет массив на 8 байт. Управитесь?

Comment: @KoVadim, вы мне напомнили фокус с картами - когда надо быстро назвать масть, при этом буби и черви могут быть черными, а крести и трефы - красными.

Взрослые редко справляются с этой задачей, а вот дети - очень часто )

Я и забыл уже про столбик) Только меня чувство не покидает, что "своя" реализация все равно будет медленнее "чужой"

Еще раз - arduino не знаю, но вот [это](https://code.google.com/p/isr-uc-ros-pkg/source/browse/stacks/mrl_robots/upload_arduino/arduino+libraries/ros_lib/std_msgs/Int64.h?r=386) разве не подойдет? Тогда и столбик городить не придется.

Comment: @KoVadim Насчёт быстрого возведения в степень всё понятно, но вопрос-то был про вычисление произведения.больших чисел по заданному модулю.

Comment: Смешно, когда программисты пытаются реализовывать математику, в которой не рубят, и делают самые прямолинейные и медленные решения=) И ведь зарабатывают больше фундаментальщиков, в рашке же рабочий класс победил, а вшивые интеллигентишки со своей игрой в бисер без задач никому не нужны=) Вот здесь немного полезной информации об RSA: http://z0mbie.daemonlab.org/rsa.html

Answer (score 2):

Почти авторская идея:

`(r*a) % n = ((r>>15) * a15n + (r & 32767) * a) % n) % n`,
причём `a15n = (a<<15) % n` можно вычислить до цикла.

Дело в том, что `r=A*32768+B`, где `А=r>>15, B=r&32767`.

P.S. Если `a` не слишком велико, то без первого `%n` можно обойтись.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, вам поможет "Искусство программирования", том 2 (3 издание), Д. Кнут:
пункт 4.3 Арифметика многократной точности: 4.3.1 Классические алгоритмы (умножение m-разрядного на n-разрядное число с получением (m+n)-разрядного), 4.3.2 Модулярная арифметика.

Условия, насколько я понимаю, идентичные, что и предпосылки в повествовании Д. Кнута.